# Error en servicio web: Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

$usu = $_REQUEST['usu'];
$pas = $_REQUEST['pas'];

try{
    // establecemos la conexion con PDO
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=pagina.000webhostapp.com;port=3306;dbname=id554244_basededatos", "id453244_usuario", "contraseña");

    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // establecemos el juego de caracteres utf8
    $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    // consulta para obtener el alumno con dicho usuario y contraseña
    $consulta_sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE codAlu=? AND pasUsu=?";

    // preparamos la consulta
    $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta_sql);

    // ejecutamos la consulta con los aparametros del array, entrecomillado porque son varchar
    $resultado->execute(array("$usu", "$pas"));// guardamos en resultado la tabla virtual que devele la consulta

    $datos = array();

    foreach($resultado as $row){
        $datos[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($datos);

}catch(Exception $e){
    die("Error: " . $e->GetMessage());
}finally{// esto se ejecuta haya o no error
    $conexion = null;
}

?>
```

No entiendo por qué sale este error, puesto que los parámetros de el PDO están correctos (no estoy seguro del puerto, pero ya he probado con varios y sigue sin funcionar).

Comment: Puede ser el puerto, alguna configuración en `my.cnf`, que se esté bloqueando la conexión en `/etc/hosts.deny`... son varios los motivos por los que podría no estar conectándose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el formato de URL al que te estás conectando, la base de datos mysql parece estar alojada en un servidor diferente a donde están los archivos PHP:

```
host=pagina.000webhostapp.com;
```

Deberías averiguar con el proveedor de hosting, si la IP desde donde estás intentando conectarte está habilitada para hacer conexiones de **MySQL remoto** hacia servidor en donde está alojada la base de datos.

Si estás trabajando desde localhost, es muy probable que no puedas conectarte tampoco.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta que recibes indica que no recibe absolutamente ninguna respuesta, puedes descartar problemas de autenticación.
Asegurate de estar conectando al host y puerto adecuado. Si es así, comprueba el firewall del host y/o de la máquina desde la que quieres conectar.  Muy importante también lo que te ha dicho Alfonso, comprueba que la configuración de mysql del host permite conexiones externas.

Una buena forma para ayudarte a diagnosticar el problema es intentar conectar a mano con algún cliente mysql de software, por ejemplo Heidisql

http://www.heidisql.com/

Descárgalo y prueba a conectar a la misma base de datos, si no lo consigues significa efectivamente que dirección de host, puerto o configuración de mysql necesitan ser revisados.

Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

Si el servidor donde está la base de datos es el mismo donde está el código, lo recomendable es utilizar "localhost"... este error desapareció conmigo pues el servicio de hosting nunca notificaba cuando había un cambio de IP; por otro lado, sería bueno que obtuvieras la IP de la URL que indicas como host